# How to verify Spring + AspecJ Transactions?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-transactions

I'm pretty sure transactions are not being applied in my Spring Boot application, even though I am using `@EnableTransactionManagement(mode=AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)` & have `spring-aspects` in my app.

### Configuration

```
@Configuration
public class DatastoreConfig{    
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){ ///... }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource){
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public String databaseSchema(){
        return "mySchema";
    }

    @Bean
    public OpenSessionInViewInterceptor openSessionInViewInterceptor(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
        OpenSessionInViewInterceptor result = new OpenSessionInViewInterceptor();
        result.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
        return result;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter){
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setPackagesToScan( Main.class.getPackage().getName() + ".model");
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factory.setJpaProperties(getJpaProperties());
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter(){
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
        vendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform(PostgreSQL9Dialect.class.getName());
        return vendorAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory(HibernateEntityManagerFactory emf){
        SessionFactoryImpl sf = (SessionFactoryImpl) emf.getSessionFactory();
        return sf;
    }

    private Properties getJpaProperties() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
//        props.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "validate");
        props.put("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy", ImprovedNamingStrategy.class.getName());
        props.put("hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans", "true");
        props.put("jadira.usertype.autoRegisterUserTypes", "true");
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) throws PropertyVetoException {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager(emf);
        transactionManager.setRollbackOnCommitFailure(true);
        transactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

}
```

#### Main class

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)
@ComponentScan
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
@EnableEntityLinks
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableApiResources(apiPrefix = "")
@EnableJpaRepositories(transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager")
@EnableHypermediaSupport(type = EnableHypermediaSupport.HypermediaType.HAL)
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@Slf4j
public class Main extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(
            SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Main.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object[] sources = {
            Main.class,
            TomcatConfig.class // include for embedded tomcat...
        };
        ConfigurableApplicationContext result = SpringApplication.run(sources, args);
    }

}
```

### Attempt to verify

One of the ways I was trying to verify was by running

```
@Component
public class SomeService{
    @Transactional
    @Override
    protected void tryItOut(){
            // this is always false
            boolean declarativeTransaction = TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive();
            // this throws an exception
            TransactionStatus aspect = TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus();
    }
}
```

However, if I insert a call to `transactionManager.getTransaction(new DefaultTransactionDefinition());` beforehand, `declarativeTransaction` is `true`.

Any advice on how to set up @Transactions / verify they're working?

Comment: I don't believe your code. In particular, you're "overriding" a method that that code can't possibly override. I suspect a self-call issue; post real code.

Comment: I trimmed things down for brevity. `tryItOut` was actually `doSave` with a few gory / unrelated pieces of information that I had carved up to try and debug. 

Even if it were a self-call issue, a transaction boundary was set a layer up in the controller, so at this point we should have a transaction regardless of tryItOut's boundary

Comment: Ah--do you have `aspectjrt` on the runtime classpath?

Comment: Yup, all bundled in with Maven. Also, `@Aspect` advice works perfectly fine too. Just not transactions

Comment: Mode `aspectj` means you use aspects for weaving (load or compile time) it doesn't mean you are using proxies. However the addition of `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` uses proxies. So what should be used. Also you seem to do a lot of work to not use Spring Boot.

Comment: @M.Deinum - for `@Transactional` to work I *do* want weaving enabled, right? And for `@Aspect`'s to be picked up, I need `@EnableASpectJAutoProxy, right? 

I tried dropping `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` but still no dice.

Comment: Making `@Transactional` work has nothing to do with weaving. With weaving it will weave the aspects using load- or compile time weaving.  Your configuration doesn't do anything in that regard. So no you don't need weaving for transactions, just use the default (that is proxy based).

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration is contradicting itself.

```
@EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)
```

Means you are using loadtime or compile time weaving of the aspects. Judging on your configuration you aren't using that. If I have to judge your configuration you are just using basic proxies no weaving.Just remove `AdviceMode.ASPECTJ` and it will work, you also don't need the `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` as applying transactions has nothing to do with that it (it can work without it).

Also your configuration is doing a lot to basically not use Spring Boot. You have configured a lot of things that spring boot already does for you automatically, manually.

Spring Boot already configures the following for you (just by only specifying `@EnableAutoConfiguration`.

1. EntityManagerFactory
2. DataSource
3. JdbcTemplate
4. Transaction Setup
5. OpenEntityManagerInView
6. Spring Web Sockets
7. Hypermedia support
8. Spring Data JPA setup

You can remove a whole lot of your configuration and put some properties in `application.properties`.

If you really need the `SessionFactory` instead of doing the casting yourself I strongly suggest the use of the `HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean`.

I would suspect the following main class to still work (with transaction enabled).

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@Slf4j
public class Main extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(
            SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Main.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object[] sources = {
            Main.class,
            TomcatConfig.class // include for embedded tomcat...
        };
        ConfigurableApplicationContext result = SpringApplication.run(sources, args);
    }

}
```

With this `DatastoreConfig` class

```
@Configuration
public class DatastoreConfig{    

    @Bean
    public FactoryBean<SessionFactory> sessionFactory(EntityManagerFactory emf){
        HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean jpaSessionFactoryBean = new HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean();
        jpaSessionFactoryBean.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return jpaSessionFactoryBean;
    }
}
```

And this `application.properties`

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true
spring.jpa.properties.jadira.usertype.autoRegisterUserTypes=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
```

You probably need to add some `spring.datasource.` properties to setup your datasource correctly. Also judging from the fact that you had a `OpenSessionInViewInterceptor` you used that instead of the `OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor` (or filter). So you might even be able to remove that.

Not sure if that is al your configuration but you might be able to remove/trim down even more. I suggest a look at the Spring Boot reference guide to get a feeling for what is already automatically configured.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed post. I've got to do some more reading about the AspectJ setup it seems, as I'm not fully grasping it.

Comment: So, part of my problem is that I don't want to use Proxies as there are some cases where I'm injecting concrete classes (and getting the dreaded `Cannot cast $Proxy192 to FooService`.

Comment: I thought all that I needed to do for AspectJ Transactions were those configs, but it sounds like I need to either: instrument my compile or runtime? Is that right?

Comment: You are also using `@EnableAsync` which also creates a proxy so you would have to switch that to AspectJ also. You should indeed add either compile time or load time weaving (or find a way to work around needing concrete classes as you should be programming to interfaces).